# Cucumber-js: World constructor example with phantomjs

Tags: testing, phantomjs, cucumberjs

In the [cucumber-js page](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) is showed an example with Zombie:

```
// features/support/world.js
var zombie = require('zombie');
var WorldConstructor = function WorldConstructor(callback) {

  var browser = new zombie();

  var world = {
    browser: browser,                        // this.browser will be available in step definitions
    visit: function(url, callback) {         // this.visit will be available in step definitions
      this.browser.visit(url, callback);
    }
  };

  callback(world); // tell Cucumber we're finished and to use our world object instead of 'this'
};
exports.World = WorldConstructor;
```

It is possible use Phantomjs instead of Zombie?

Can someone show me an example of world.js with it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```
// features/support/world.js
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");

var WorldConstructor = function WorldConstructor(callback) {
  var world = {
    driver: new webdriver.Builder()
      .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
      .build()
  };

  callback(world);
};

exports.World = WorldConstructor;
```

I had to install phantomjs:

```
npm install phantomjs
```

**Chromedriver**

You can also use chromedriver as follows:

```
npm install chromedriver
```

Remember to change driver to:

```
driver: new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
  .build()
```

Comment: could you please help me out with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297950/cucumberjs-how-to-use-worldconstructor-across-different-features

Comment: @Valay Sorry but I have not used this for two years.